# convert html (ï) for xml php

Tags: php, html, xml

I have a piece of HTML code which I save into a xml file (description of a product). When I import the xml it hangs on the following character: ï and maybe others.

How can I convert the html code to valid xml?

I pass convert the html with the following piece of php and put it into a CDATA block.

```
str_replace(array(chr(169),chr(153),chr(174)),'',trim(str_replace_first('</tr>', '<table class="attribute">', str_replace('valign=top', '', str_replace('class="normal"', '', GetBetween($product_page, '<td colspan=2>&nbsp;</td>', '</table>'))))));
```

I've tryed htmlspecialchars, htmlentities with UTF-8 but nothing helped.

Comment: Show us *how* you tried to use the different functions.

Comment: The character “ï” is just as valid in XML as it is in HTML. There is no reason to convert it in any way. You just need to make sure that the HTML fragment is in the same character encoding as the XML document. If it is not, then you need to convert the entire HTML fragment from one character encoding to another. The way to do this depends on the source encoding and on the availability of tools in your environment.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
$data = htmlentities($data, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: Thanks, but this didnt work like I mentioned the ï for example remain ï.

Comment: Ok. Do you have some more information regarding this problem, like the XML code or complete line where it is stopping ?

Comment: `<description>Een krachtige processor geïnstalleerd.</description>`

this is for example a xml line where the code breaks. Also I noticed this. In my original xml file I have:
`<productgroep>Accu&#xef;s / Batterijlader</productgroep>`

in the new xml file saved by simplexml this get automaticly converted to:

`<productgroep>Accuïs / Batterijlader</productgroep>`

Comment: Ok. You may try using [iconv](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) function of PHP then.